# Does Teemo Blind blocks Darius Ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

I would like to know if Teemo use Blind, then does Darius' Ultimate get blocked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Darius' Ultimate will still hit you. This is not because of anything special with Darius' Ultimate, but more with how Blind works. It mostly deals with auto-attacks and doesn't affect abilities.

> #### Blind
>
> The target will miss auto-attacks, incurring the message "Miss" above their attack target.
>   Blind only mitigates the physical damage portion of an attack, including physical damage sourced from a physical on-hit effect. Other damage types and effects won't miss. See: On-hit effects.
>   Abilities that apply on-hit effects will also miss.
>   Blind is considered a form of damage mitigation. As such, it is applied after  Thornmail's passive.
>   Does not interrupt channeling.
>   The duration is affected by crowd control reduction.
>   The effect can be removed by all cleansing effects (except for Mikael's Crucible).
>   Blind will not affect certain champion abilities.(e.g. Riven's passive Runic Blade)
>   Blinded enemies will only miss if they attack while blinded. Ranged units will still hit if the projectile fires before the blind.
>   If  ayne is blinded, she can only proc her  Silver Bolts if she tumbles. Normal auto attacks do not proc silver bolts while blinded (tested)
>   Champions with Blind:  Teemo, Quinn